# Regex Full match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to understand regular expressions:

I need to only match on **text_01** and **text_02** and filter out the tags.

```
<span>text_01<b>text_02</b>
```

I've tried to do it like:

```
(?<=<span>)(([^>]+)<b>)(.+?)(?=</b>)
```

But it captures 3 groups and and the *Full Match* includes a tag.

```
text_01<b>text_02
```

Could you give me advice on how I need to build a regex whose Full match contains only text and no tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing HTML with regular expressions can get very complicated. In general it is [not advised practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839) and better to use a parser for this (some library in whatever language you are using).

But for cases where you are sure the text content does not have `<` nor `>`, and these `<` and `>` are not nested, you could use this one:

[`[^<>]*(?=<[^<>]*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/HM1vng/4)

This only matches text that is followed by a pair of `<` and `>`.

If it is enough to test that text is followed by `<`, it can be simply:

[`[^<>]*(?=<)`](https://regex101.com/r/HM1vng/3)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need. You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

By using a non-capturing group you are able to exclude the middle `<b>` tag as a capture group, but you will never be able to get a full match without the tag included. It's not possible, a regular expression cannot skip a part while capturing. A match must be consecutive.

```
(?<=<span>)(.+?)(?:<b>)(.+?)(?=<\/b>)
```

- Full match        `text_01<b>text_02`
- Group 1.          `text_01`
- Group 2.      `text_02`